# Singular values of an operator

Tags: linear-algebra

The question asks to find the singular values of the operator $T:\mathbb{R}^3\to\mathbb{R}^2$ with matrix $$\mathcal{M}(T)=\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 1 & 0 \\ 0 & -1 & -1 \end{pmatrix}.$$

I have found that $$\mathcal{M}(T^*T)=\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 1 & 0 \\ 1 & 2 & 1 \\ 0 & 1 & 1 \end{pmatrix}.$$

The eigenvalues are: $\lambda = 0,1,3$, with corresponding eigenvectors: $v_1=(1,-1,1), v_2=(1,0,-1)$ and $v_3=(1,2,1).$

How do I know find the square root of $T^*T$ and hence the singular values of $T$?

**EDIT:** If $T:\mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}^m$, then how many singular values does $T$ have?

I think it should be $n$, but in the few questions we were given, it seems to be $m$?

Comment: Take a look at this: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singular_value. A **singular value** is the sqrare root of an **eigenvalue**. So, you have $\sqrt3, 1, 0.$

Comment: That's what I thought too, but Maple gives me only $1$ and $\sqrt{3}$.

Comment: Sure,  $0$ does not count. (Sorry...)

Comment: Why doesn't $0$ count?

Comment: Then I don't know. (One more sorry) But then edit your question because you are asking for the square root of $T^*T$.

Comment: We have another similar problem for the matrix $\mathcal{M}(T) = \begin{pmatrix} 0 & 1 \\ 2 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 \end{pmatrix}$, where $\mathcal{M}(T^*T) = \begin{pmatrix} 4 & 0 \\ 0 & 2 \end{pmatrix}$. It has eigenvalues $4$ and $2$, so singular values of $T$ are $2$ and $\sqrt{2}$. Maple gives me $0$ also. WHY??

Comment: : ((((((((((((((